# If there is an error on a sampler, how can I automatically make it go to the next sampler

Tags: performance, selenium, testing, jmeter

As you can see in the image, I loop through 4 samplers (around 400 loops in total). How can I make it so if there is an error on any of the first three samplers within the loop, to automatically go to the last sampler?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check previous sampler success using [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)  and `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)
2. In case of failure you can add a [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) as a child of the If Controller and specify the [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) to execute, in your case put the "Logout" sampler under the Test Fragment

More information: [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter)